# About this congruence implication

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am given this I don't see it at all. I've been trying to prove it for a couple days already.

We have:

$$ (X+a)^n\equiv X^n+a\mod{p} $$
With $p$ prime, and $p$ being a divisor of $n$. And we also have:

$$(X+a)^p\equiv X^p+a\mod{p}$$

From these two equations, it must follow

$$ (X+a)^{\frac{n}{p}}\equiv X^{\frac{n}{p}}+a\mod{p} $$

I don't see this at all. Could anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the second equation you made things more complicated, because for every $Y$:
$$ Y\equiv Y^p \mod p$$

if we take :$Y=(X+a)^{\frac{n}{p}}$ and $Y=X^{\frac{n}{p}}$ respectively  we have:
$$(X+a)^{\frac{n}{p}}\equiv (X+a)^n\mod p\\
 X^{\frac{n}{p}}\equiv X^n \mod p$$

Now from your first equation $ (X+a)^n\equiv X^n+a\mod{p}  $ it follows that:
$$ (X+a)^{\frac{n}{p}}\equiv X^{\frac{n}{p}}+a\mod{p} $$

Comment: Thank you so much. The second one was unneccessary, but I was reading it in a paper and they said that that was an implication of both equations. Thank you again

Comment: maybe because my equation :$Y\equiv Y^p \mod p$ is a consequence of the second equation when $a=0$ and $Y=X$

Comment: you mean when $X=0$?, then it's just Fermat's little theorem.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align} f(x)^{\color{#c00}pk}\!\equiv&\ f(x^{\color{#c00}pk})\!\!\pmod{p}\quad {\rm for}\ \ f\in\Bbb Z[x]\\
\Rightarrow\ f(x)^{k}\,  \equiv&\ f(x^{k})\pmod{p}\end{align}$

because $\, a^{\color{#c00}p}\equiv a\pmod{p}.\,\ $  The OP is case $\,f(x) = x+a,\,\ n = pk$